# How to get current session when using MapperFactoryBean?

Tags: java, spring, session, mybatis, ibatis

Disclaimer: I'm still *very* new to MyBatis & Spring so please forgive me if some detail is missing below.

I have some code which uses `MapperFactoryBean` in MyBatis to automatically manage database transactions without having to create DAO classes in my Java code. This also means that when using this approach, the user doesn't need to write any session specific code as MyBatis directly handles sessions for communicating with the database itself.

**Question:** So when the above is the case, if one wishes to get the current Session, how do you do that ?? In Hibernate you could do `getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession()` to get the current session. What is the equivalent command for MyBatis when MyBatis's `MapperFactoryBean` approach is being used to communicate with the database ?

Here are snippets of my current code:

**beans.xml:**

```
<bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
    <property name="basePackage" value="com.countries.dataaccess" />
</bean>

<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
     <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />    
</bean>

<bean id="countriesMapper" class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean">
 <property name="mapperInterface" value="com.countries.dataaccess.CountryMapper" />
     <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />         
</bean>

<bean id="countriesFacade" class="com.countries.facade.CountriesFacade" />
```

**com.countries.dataaccess.CountryMapper:**

```
public interface CountryMapper {

    public List<CountryOutlineDTO> getAllCountries(List<String> merchantType);

    public CountryDetailsDTO getCountryInfo(String countryCode);

  //etc ....
}
```

**com.countries.delegate.CountriesServiceDelegate:**

```
public interface CountriesServiceDelegate {

    public CountryDetails getCountryDetails(String countryCode, String locale) throws Exception;

    public List<CountryDetails> getAllCountryDetails(List<String> merchantTypeList, boolean verbose) throws Exception;

    public Health getDBHealth();
}
```

**com.countries.delegate.impl.CountriesServiceDelegateImpl:**

```
public class CountriesServiceDelegateImpl implements CountriesServiceDelegate {

    @Autowired
    private CountriesFacade countriesFacade;

    @Override
    public CountryDetails getCountryDetails(String countryCode, String locale) {

    //Implementation logic here ...

    }

    @Override
    public List<CountryDetails> getAllCountryDetails(List<String> merchantTypeList, boolean verbose) {

    //Implementation logic here ...

    }
}
```

**com.countries.facade:**

```
public class CountriesFacade {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("countriesMapper")
    private CountryMapper countriesMapper;

    public CountryDetails getCountryInfo(String countryCode, String locale) {

    //Implementation logic here such as xyz = countriesMapper.getCountryInfo(countryCode);

    }

    public List<CountryDetails> getAllCountries(List<String> merchantType, boolean verbose) {

    //Implementation logic here such as xyz = countriesMapper.getCountryInfo(countryCode);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi use `SqlSessionTemplate` as documented http://www.mybatis.org/spring/sqlsession.html

It will ensure that you get the same sqlsession as the mapper you are using.

You can also use `SqlSessionDaoSupport` as documented on that same page if that works better for your use case.